Determine the real numbers $a_1,a_2,...,a_n$ for which $a_1^5+a_2^5+...+a_n^5=n$ and $a_1^3+...+a_n^3=a_1 ^8+...+a_n^8$
The problem
Let $n\in N^*$. Determine the real numbers $a_1,a_2,...,a_n$ for which $a_1^5+a_2^5+...+a_n^5=n$ and $a_1^3+...+a_n^3=a_1 ^8+...+a_n^8$
my idea
This equality seems like we could use CBS to get a useful inequality.
$(a_1^5+a_2^5+...+a_n^5)(a_1^3+...+a_n^3) \geq (a_1^4+a_2^4+...+a_n^4)^2$
also we can say that $(a_1 ^8+...+a_n^8)(1+1+...+1) \geq (a_1^4+a_2^4+...+a_n^4)^2$
I don't know where to start from! Hope one of you can help me! Thanks!

Most probably {1,1,....,1} should be the answer

@MathStackexchangeIsMarvellous Yeah, but how do we demonstrate it is the only solution?

To apply CBS in the manner you describe in the first case, you need the $a_i$ to be non-negative, which doesn't seem to be specified.

Hint:  You can arrange the $a_i$ in non-decreasing order and applying Chebyshev's sum inequality to get:
$$\frac{\sum_i a_i^3}n\cdot \frac{\sum_i a_i^5}n \leqslant \frac{\sum_i a_i^8}n $$
Applying the given conditions, we realise this is an equality in this case.  Now you just need to consider when would equality be possible here.

The case of equality happens when we have $a_1^3=a_2^3=...a_n^3$ and $a_1^5=a_2^5=...= a_n^5$ so when $a_1=a_2=...=a_n$. Because $a_1+a_2+...+a_n=n$ all of them is 1. Am I right? Thanks for the hint!

@PamMunozRyan Yes, thats right! That wiki page needs to add the equality condition, will do sometime soon...
